# is there any design pattern for login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

There is a very simple 2 page website. first is login page where we can enter username and password, and the second page shows "welcome" after authentication..

Is there any design pattern that we can use for this?

I am not able think of a design pattern for such a simple website, but just wanted to get your thoughts.

One of my colleague asked this question to me!

Comment: well, i searched in google before asking the question. I was getting few UX design patterns and few other patterns like "Interaction Design Pattern". But could not find any standard one from GoF design patterns.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the [interceptor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern) (or [intercepting filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/interceptingfilter-142169.html)) comes to mind: a central filter should intercept all the requests to authentication-protected pages of the application and redirect to the login page if the user is not authenticated yet.

And if the user is already authenticated, it should let the request go to its original target.

Note that it's much more user-friendly to not redirect to a welcome page after authentication, but to the originally-requested page:

- User wants to go to /my-profile
- Filter notices the user is not authenticated, and /my-profile requires authentication. It redirects to login page
- user logs in
- server redirects to /my-profile which is where the user asked to go originally.

Note that I know nothing about asp.net, so this pattern might be easy to implement or very hard: I have no idea. Java EE webapps have this notion of filters which are typically used for authentication, the way described above.